# Use Built-in Azure IAM for permissions on Azure Functions app vs an App registration to enumerate tenant-wide resources?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, identity-management

I have an azure functions application written in PowerShell to provide reporting on various kinds of resources in our organization. On my machine it works perfect but once deployed to Azure Functions it produces no results which I'm basically 99.999% confident is because the Azure functions application has no access to resources outside it's resource group.

**What I'm trying to accomplish**
I would like the azure functions application to be able to enumerate the resources in various subscriptions for the purposes of reporting / audit.

My organization has provided me with what appears to be an app registration but I don't think this is the right approach as that is something I would consume in code to facilitate functionality VS setting the IAM of the functions app should allow me to make the app itself inside azure able to enumerate resources in different subscriptions as a reader for example.

is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

> **What I'm trying to accomplish** I would like the azure functions application to be able to enumerate the resources in various subscriptions for the purposes of reporting / audit.

You can create one managed identity for your function app and give that managed identity access as atleast Reader or Contributor role at the subscription level. Once managed identity is enabled for the Function, You can run it from anywhere.

[image]

[image]

[image]

> My organization has provided me with what appears to be an app registration but I don't think this is the right approach

You can refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74904428/how-to-securely-give-external-application-access-to-key-vault-in-azure/74919196#74919196) by **@Sourav** and refer method **2.** And convert the existing app registration to a multitenant application and call it in another tenant via the `url` given in the answer. And then provide **atleast contributor or Reader role to the Multitenant app in both the subscriptions** to access the resources.

Then you can use the same Application registration Client Id and Client Secret to access Azure resources by referring my SO thread answer **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75824158/accessing-storage-account-from-azure-function-powershell/75830682#75830682)**, Where I have utilized Application Registration to access storage account in my Function Powershell code.